# Configuring Request Headers in BITS (Microsoft Background Intelligent Transfer Service) in C#

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-headers, microsoft-bits

I am trying to download a file through BITS and the job is failing ( giving me a error) as i failed to mention "referer" in http header in the GET request.

```
        BitsManager manager = new BitsManager();           
        manager.EnumJobs(JobOwner.CurrentUser);
        BitsJob newJob = manager.CreateJob(j.filename, JobType.Download);
        j.jobID = newJob.JobId;

        newJob.AddFile(j.serverLink, "C:\\Downloads\\" + j.filename);
        newJob.Priority = JobPriority.ForeGround;
        newJob.MinimumRetryDelay = 60;
        manager.OnJobTransferred += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(manager_OnJobTransferred);
        manager.OnJobModified += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(manager_OnJobModified);
        newJob.Resume();
```

Is there a way to *configure the header* for the GET request for the jobs ?

Thanks a ton,

Sunny

Answer (score 3):

BITS lets you set custom headers on the request.

The BITS team at Microsoft now has a page on [Calling into BITS from .NET and C# using reference DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bits-dot-net) plus a complete sample call [BITS Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/BITS-Manager) on GitHub.

I've just tried a custom modification to the sample. In setJobPropertyControl.xaml.cs, I cast the job to an IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions like this:

```
var jobHttpOptions = job as BITS4.IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions;
```

I had to also do

```
using BITS4 = BITSReference4_0;
```

Then I could

```
jobHttpOptions.SetCustomHeaders (text);
```

where text is the header you need to set. You can set mulitple headers by just concatenating a big string ("referer: http://www.example.com\r\nx-other-header: another header\r\n"). Note that HTTP headers must be seperated with \r\n!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your HTTP server may not be compatible with the HTTP requirements of BITS

> ### HTTP Requirements for BITS Downloads
>
> BITS supports HTTP and HTTPS downloads and uploads and requires that
>   the server supports the HTTP/1.1 protocol. For downloads, the HTTP
>   server's Head method must return the file size and its Get method must
>   support the Content-Range and Content-Length headers. As a result,
>   BITS only transfers static file content and generates an error if you
>   try to transfer dynamic content, unless the ASP, ISAPI, or CGI script
>   supports the Content-Range and Content-Length headers.
>
> BITS can use an
>   HTTP/1.0 server as long as it meets the Head and Get method
>   requirements.
>
> To support downloading ranges of a file, the server must
>   support the following requirements:
>
> - Allow MIME headers to include the standard Content-Range and Content-Type headers,  plus a maximum of 180 bytes of other headers.
> - Allow a maximum of two CR/LFs between the HTTPheaders and the first boundary string.

For more information check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)